# Crash on read DataGridView

Tags: c#

this code must read the values ​​from a datagridview and save them in a list, but the following error is generated: 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.

**C# Code#:**

```
    List<string> TotaleOreGiornaliere = new List<string>();
    int conta = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridViewPrincipale.Rows)
    {                        
       TotaleOreGiornaliere.Add(dr.Rows[conta].Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString());
       conta++;
    }
```

Comment: The DGV datasource is a DataTable.  Add to the DataTable instead of the DGV.  The DGV will then get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> TotaleOreGiornaliere = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
   TotaleOreGiornaliere.Add(dr.Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString());
}
```

try this above code snippet will work.

```
dr.Rows[conta].Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString()
```

***this will not work as DataGridViewRow does not contain property for Rows***

kindly look at this document [DataGridViewRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a DataRow:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dataGridViewPrincipale.Rows) { 
  TotaleOreGiornaliere.Add(dr.Rows[conta].Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString()); 
  conta++; 
}
```